# Как поменять кодировку атрибутов headers

Tags: python-3.x

Ситуация следующая: качаю парсером файл. Хочу выцепить имя файла. Но на запрос:

`file.headers.get('Content-Disposition')`

он возвращает:

`'attachment; filename="4_328_Ð\x97Ð°ÐºÑ\x83Ð¿Ð¾Ñ\x87Ð½Ð°Ñ\x8f Ð´Ð¾ÐºÑ\x83Ð¼ÐµÐ½Ñ\x82Ð°Ñ\x86Ð¸Ñ\x8f Ñ\x87. 1.docx"'`

Если бы это была обычная страница, сработало бы file.encoding = 'utf-8'. Тут не работает.

**Вопрос: Подскажите, как привести название файла в нормальную кириллицу.**

В данном случае корректное название файла должно быть "4_328_Закупочная документация ч. 1.docx")

Comment: Не пробовали прямо так и поменять `file.encoding = 'utf-8'`? Или `file.headers.encoding = 'utf-8'`

Comment: Пробовал. Без результата